# Four mutually adjacent US states (not the Four Corners)

Tags: geography, graph-theory

The question [Is there a proof that a map of the United States requires 4 colors?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/219/is-there-a-proof-that-a-map-of-the-united-states-requires-4-colors) was answered by showing that Nevada has five neighbors, each adjacent to the next (an "odd wheel").  "Adjacent" here means that they have a common border which is more than a single point.

Another possible proof would be to find a state with *three* neighbors, each adjacent to the next.  That would constitute a "4-clique": four states which are mutually adjacent, in that each one is adjacent to each of the three others.   (By our definition of "adjacent", Utah / Arizona / New Mexico / Colorado does not count.)

There actually is a 4-clique in the map of the United States.  What are the four states?

Comment: Hm, I don t think that is a puzzle, just a quiz question (and an easy one)...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a puzzle nor about a puzzle. It would make an interesting comment to the cited puzzle, though.

Comment: @NateEldridge, is there any legal trickery here, e.g. Yellowstone jurisprudence?

Comment: I am referring to the physical state boundaries.  But it's true that you may not see them at first glance.

Comment: @BmyGuest I understand the puzzle of it now. It was just poorly worded.

Comment: @dcfyj: Do you have any suggestions as to how to improve the wording?

Comment: @dcfyj  even with the answer I think it is a trivia question, not a puzzle.(Albeit slightly more challenging than 'totally easy'.) we should not encourage 'puzzles' which really are just questions with a minor hint, or there will soon bi zillions of it.

Comment: I would clarify what you mean by the 4-clique. Like State 1 shares a border with states 2,3 and 4, State 2 shares a border with states 1,3 and 4, etc

Comment: @NateEldredge That is not meant to discourage you from this site (welcome, btw!), but if you stick around for a while (including meta) you will better understand what I mean.

Comment: @dcfyj: Okay, I thought that was inherent in the word "mutually", but I tried spelling it out.

Comment: Excuse my spelling. iPad is driving me mad with auto corrections!

Comment: It is, but that escaped me when I first read it. It wasn't until I read the answer that I understood what you meant.

Comment: @BmyGuest: It seemed to me like an extension of the four-color map question (which was well received): in some sense, I'm asking for a solution of that problem with additional restrictions.  But I see your point.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a trivia question, not a puzzle.

Comment: Ok, I have posted it as an answer on the four-color puzzle instead.  Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> New York, bordered by Rhode Island, Connecticut, and Massachusets.  The New York - Rhode Island border just happens to be under water, between [Misquamicut Beach and Fisher's Island](https://www.google.com/maps/place/41%C2%B016'52.6%22N+71%C2%B053'05.7%22W/@41.27603,-71.885261,13.04z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d41.28129!4d-71.884927).

Comment: Nice. Just a little bit slow on my part. I had to google Rhode Island and New York, it said they do border, but I couldn't see how.  Good job and explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's

> New York, Massachusetts, Connecticut, & Rhode Island.

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Comment: @NateEldredge, that's an interesting fact "The state [R.I.] also shares a short maritime border with New York."

Comment: @John Michigan and Illinois also have a (submerged) border, which is what put me onto the solution.

Comment: @RoadieRich, yeah that's kind of good cocktail party fact! Haha...